# Anaconda Navigator not showing Pycharm Application

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, anaconda3

I have two computers, one laptop with the latest Ubuntu, and a desktop with Windows 10.

I have installed Anaconda Navigator on both.

My issue is that when I launch Anaconda Navigator on my windows pc, there is no pycharm in it. See picture below:

[image]

When I launch Anaconda Navigator from my laptop, its there the way I expected.

See picture below:

[image]

Both of my machines have Pycharm installed before I installed Anaconda Navigator.

I have spent a few hours now googling every possible variation of my question and I can think off. I can find a few times the question has been asked but no answer. Some people even say its not possible.

Any advice or pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated. I don't know where to keep looking.

All the best,
Carty

Comment: I updated Navigator on my Laptop and Pycharm appeared

Answer (score 2):

My problem is similar to yours - I have installed Pycharm but in Anaconda Navigator the icon below Pycharm is "Install", which should be "Launch".

I solved it by adding the directory path of Pycharm to the configuration of  Anaconda Navigator.

Open the Anaconda Navigator, click "File" - "Preferences", add the directory path of Pycharm in the "Pycharm Pro path" or "Pycharm CE path", depending on your Pycharm type. The directory path here should be the whole directory, for example, "C:\Pycharm".

Wish it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems only when the Pycharm is installed in the default directory will the Navigator show its icon. I installed both on my laptop and PC(both win10), one in the default location the other in a custom location and the icon only showed on the default one.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for letting me know, I appreciate that. I knew it was gonna be some silly reason.